# How to find if element exists in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this part of the code is not working.

```
$partofcode ='
userid=8;
if ($(".btn-follow[userid=\'+userid+\']").length) {
alert("ok found");
}';
```

this part of the code is working

```
$partofcode ='
if ($(".btn-follow[userid=\'8\']").length) {
alert("ok found");
}';
```

what is wrong here?

answer here below

```
$partofcode ='
userid=8;
if ($(".btn-follow[userid=\'"+userid+"\']").length) {
alert("ok found");
}';
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong. Can you please clarify correctly?

Comment: arent you missing the var before userid? "var userid=8;" Also did you check userid is actually passing the value correctly? set an alert before the if to check alert(userid);

Comment: no problem is solved, there were two double quotes missing. this var=8 was just for testing.

Answer (score 2):

You have your quotation marks messed up.

You need:

```
".btn-follow[userid=\'" + userid + "\']"
```

Note how the two string constants are each correctly enclosed in double-quotes (and with the single quotes escaped so that they don't terminate the outer PHP string variable).

Comment: the code is part of a php-variable so the single quotes need to be escaped

Comment: ok i got it. your answer with escaped single quotes.

Comment: Ah, I didn't spot the PHP gunk in there...